# Abbreviating a name

Tags: c, strings

This is a question from a CS diploma question set :

> Make a program that will create an abbreviation of any given name using the initials. For example if the name if "John Doe", the program will output "J.D".

My Code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *abbr (const char *s) {

    int keywords = 1;
    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++)
        if (s[i] == ' ') keywords++;

    char *ret = (char *)malloc(2*keywords);
    if (!ret) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *str = strdup(s);
    int i = 0;
    for (char *tok=strtok(str, " "); tok; tok=strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        ret [i++] = *tok;
        ret [i++] = '.';
    }
    ret [--i] = 0;
    free(str);
    return ret;
}

int main (void) {
    char name[] = "John Doe";
    char *s = abbr(name);
    puts (s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

With respect to the question, is this a good enough solution? Is there a better way to achieve the same thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Is that a direct quote of the problem statement?  In particular, is only one `.` required for that example input, that we'd normally write in English as `J.D.`?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> char *abbr (const char *s) {
> ```

Good - appropriate use of `const` here.

> ```
> char *ret = (char *)malloc(2*keywords);
> ```

The cast is unnecessary, as `malloc()` returns a `void*` - which can be assigned to any pointer type in C (unlike C++).  See [Do I cast the result of `malloc()`?](//stackoverflow.com/a/605858/4850040)

> ```
> if (!ret) {
> ```

Again, good - avoid dereferencing a null pointer.  I would take a different action if the allocation fails - just return a null pointer to the caller, who is in a better position to decide whether to abort the whole program, and whether to write an error message to `stderr`.

> ```
> char *str = strdup(s);
> ```

`strdup()` allocates memory, so this must be checked for a null return just like `malloc()`.  There's an additional complication here that if we return from this point, we'll need to free `ret` before doing so.  Personally, I'd remove the use of `strtok()` so that we don't need to copy the input here.  `strtok()` has a terrible interface, and I consider it a misfeature of the C library.

> ```
> char name[] = "John Doe";
> char *s = abbr(name);
> ```

The requirement is for a program to *create an abbreviation of any given name*.  This is a program that creates an abbreviation of one hard-coded name.  I don't think it's really in the spirit of the requirements to have a program that needs to be edited and recompiled to be given a different name.  All the user to provide the name as program arguments, or on the standard input stream.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather start with a very simple approach. Why not just **print out** the **capital** letters?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *namestr = "Hi my Four Names";

    char *pos = namestr;
    char c = ' ';
    while (c) {
        c = *pos++;
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            putchar(c);
            putchar('.');
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

output : `H.F.N.`

Followed by a discussion about human names and strings in C. This is something that has to be defined in a question. Names can be very complicated, not only in exotic languages (McEnroe, van Gogh, Jean-Marie). And the rules for the initials are based on that.

You should at least describe your approach. And not silently complicate a simple task (simple, but unclear).

Create a new string (with malloc)? Or just output the initials "J.D." if the string is "John Doe"? Do a sanity check on the name?

**good enough?**

Yes that is the problem: it is *too* good in some ways.

Can you tell me what kind of CS diploma that is? Is there a context? How is the code entered and evaluated?

**achieve the same thing**

What exactly? How did you interpret this unclear task?

**if the name if**

Are you citing or paraphrasing?

Comment: `c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'` is less portable than `isupper((unsigned char)c)`.